# Work out length of time between two dates

Tags: javascript, time

Im trying to work out how long a game character has existed for... or apply it to anything. Length of time user has existed.
I understand how to get my two values. Either from state or the database track when i user joins.
But how to work out the difference efficiently is my real question.
My idea has been to get the two time in seconds since 1970 form. Then convert the difference into second mins hours days etc.
Is there any other ideas people have or a plugin i can use?

Answer (score -1):

You can calculate time diffs using the built-in `Date` class.

```js
async function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

(async () => {
    let t1 = new Date();
    console.log({ t1 })
    await sleep(3000);
    let t2 = new Date();
    console.log({ t2 })
    let dt = new Date(t2 - t1);
    console.log(dt.getSeconds());
})();
```